# Display info in different component on mouseover of element in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app like the image, with a sidebar component and a lazy loaded component with users in it.

What I want is to be able to hover (onmouseover) on an user card and that the user info (photo, name and other properties) appear on the sidebar as well (as shown on image).

Is possible to achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

[image: I want to achieve this]

Comment: Of course, you could write a stateful service which is injected into both components where you can store the currently hovered user

Comment: Kudos for showing exactly what you want to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BehaviourSubject  service

```
messageSource: BehaviorSubject<string>;
```

and instantiate inside your constructor

```
this.messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>();
```

in your component you can do this,

```
this.yourService.messageSource.next('whatvermessage');
```

and if you want to subscribe to it, you can do

```
this.yourService.messageSource.asObservable().subscribe((value: string) => {

});
```

Comment: Thank you @Sajeetharan, I'm implementing it to see if it works.